# Problem Deploying safe-global/safe-contracts to custom network

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets, gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I am having a small issue deploying the [`safe-contracts`](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts)  to a custom network. I have gone through the process of deploying the [singleton factory](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory) and was able to get it deployed without a problem. When I tried to deploy the rest of the contracts, the script only made it through the first 3 contracts. For some reason it got hung up on the 4th contract, `CompatibilityFallbackHandler`.

I've tried various combinations of gas price/gas limit to no avail, I've made sure all wallets are funded, even tried funding the singleton factory, is there a step I missed somewhere? Any help is appreciated!

[Singleton Factory Address](https://explorer.giltestnet.com/address/0x914d7Fec6aaC8cd542e72Bca78B30650d45643d7)

[image]